# Create data from before row

Tags: r

```
example <- data.frame(x = c(1000, ""  ,""  ,"" ))
```

What is the R´s function to get this?

```
example <- data.frame(x = c(1000, 500, 250, 125))
```

Comment: Please narrow down your question to the code problem you are having. How is the rate of extinguishment calculated? Just having or is there another model afoot? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming nothing "fancy" is going on here, you can:

- start with the second position (i)
- find previous value (i-1) and split it
- insert the result in position i

Notice that I use `NA` instead of `""` because this will coerce your vector into a character. Math is not possible on character vectors without coercing it to numeric first.

```
x <- c(1000, NA, NA, NA)

for (i in 2:length(x)) {
  x[i] <- x[i-1]/2
}

> x
[1] 1000  500  250  125
```

Comment: `x[1] / 2 ^ (0 : (length(x) - 1))` ?

Comment: Or `x[1] ^ (seq_along(x) - 1L)`.